# Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable for two tables?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Usually, you keep username and password fields in one table (for example Users). In this case it is easy to use `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`. However, what if I have password in a separate Passwords table. How do you uses Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable to have *identityColumn* in a one table (Users) and *credentialColumn* in other table (Passwords)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend creating a table view from Users and Passwords tables. Than you would specify the view as *tableName* for Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable.

Comment: @David Weinraub. Thank you. Views are quite useful. For me I would like to learn more about stored procedures :-)